# How to implement exponential delay/sleep for try & catch

Tags: java, try-catch, retry-logic

I am trying to write another decorator like the `RetriableProcessorDecorator` below (as a separate class) so that
it does an exponential delay on retry. For example, if a message fails to be processed, we wait 1 second (should be configurable), then 2s, then 4s, then 8s, then 16s, etc. I would want to use thread instead of busy wait since it is less expensive. I wrote a new class `RetriableProcessorExponentialDecorator` that does this, but I'm not sure if this is the right approach to take.

RetriableProcessorDecorator.java:

```
@Slf4j
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
public class RetriableProcessorDecorator implements.   
AbsMessageProcessorDecorator {
private final AbsMessageProcessor messageProcessor;
@Autowired
private AbsMessageActiveMQConfiguration configuration;

@Override
public void onMessage(AbsMessage message) throws Exception {
    int executionCounter = 0;
    final int maxRetries = this.configuration.getExceptionRetry() + 1;
    do {
        executionCounter++;
        try {
            this.messageProcessor.onMessage(message);
        } catch (RetriableException e) {
            log.info("Failed to process message. Retry #{}", executionCounter);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // We don't retry on this, only RetriableException.
            throw e;
        }
    } while (executionCounter < maxRetries);
}
}
```

RetriableProcessorExponentialDecorator.java (new class I'm implementing):

```
public class RetriableProcessorExponentialDecorator implements AbsMessageProcessorDecorator {
  private final AbsMessageProcessor messageProcessor;
  @Autowired
  private AbsMessageActiveMQConfiguration configuration;

  @Override
  public void onMessage(AbsMessage message) throws Exception {
    int executionCounter = 0;
    int delayCounter = 1000;
    final int maxRetries = this.configuration.getExceptionRetry() + 1;
    do {
      executionCounter++;
      try {
        this.messageProcessor.onMessage(message);
      } catch (RetriableException e) {
        log.info("Failed to process message. Retry #{}", executionCounter);
        Thread.sleep(delayCounter);
        delayCounter = delayCounter * 2;
      } catch (Exception e) {
        // We don't retry on this, only RetriableException.
        throw e;
      }
    } while (executionCounter < maxRetries && delayCounter < Long.MAX_VALUE);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general I think your approach is fine.

However, if you wanted to make it configurable (i.e. more useful) then you could do something like:

```
double multiplier = 2.0; // make this configurable
...
delayCounter = (long) (delayCounter * (Math.pow(multiplier, executionCounter)));
Thread.sleep(delayCounter);
```

You could also add a way to configure a maximum delay which might be handy for some use-cases, e.g.:

```
long maxDelay = 300000; // 5 minutes
...
if (delayCounter > maxDelay) {
   delayCounter = maxDelay;
}
Thread.sleep(delayCounter);
```

Comment: You do not need to multiply by delayCounter ; double delay = Math.pow(MULTIPLIER, retryCounter++);

Comment: I believe the first factor has a role, @abbas : it's the first delay. Here's a version with more explicit variable names :
currentDelay = (long) (baseDelay * (Math.pow(multiplier, executionCounter)));
This way you can have your first loop delay (baseDelay) be something else than 1.

Comment: Won't you want your first retry to be as soon as possible? e.g. after 1ms?

Comment: @abbas, use-cases will vary, of course. You may want to delay the first retry or you may not. Fortunately any developer can choose the behavior based on their requirements.